# Cannot find a way to decrypt a JWE token in python (but created in ASP.Net) using jwcrypto

Tags: python, asp.net, encryption, jwt

I am having difficulties decrypting my JWE token in python once it has been encrypted using ASP.Net.

Here is my C# code (fake passwords):

```
var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ae743683f78d498a9026d0c87020b9d3"));
var secret = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MbPeShVmYq3t6w9z"));

var signingCreds = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
var encryptingCreds = new EncryptingCredentials(secret, SecurityAlgorithms.Aes128KW, SecurityAlgorithms.Aes128CbcHmacSha256);
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var jwtSecurityToken = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(
    _issuer,
    _audience,
    new ClaimsIdentity(claimsList),
    DateTime.Now,
    _expires,
    DateTime.Now,
    signingCreds,
    encryptingCreds);

var token = handler.WriteToken(jwtSecurityToken);
```

The token looks like this when using the encrypting credentials (should `typ` not be `JWE`?):

```
{
    {
        "alg": "A128KW",
        "enc": "A128CBC-HS256",
        "typ": "JWT"
    }.{
        "userId": "151aedd5-76c3-4eb2-8b73-a16004315731",
        "prop1": "test1",
        "prop2": "test2",
        "nbf": 1549894420,
        "exp": 1550240017,
        "iat": 1549894420,
        "iss": "https://localhost:56880/",
        "aud": "https://localhost:56880/"
    }
}
```

This is the token when encrypted:

```
eyJhbGciOiJBMTI4S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.4w4MZv5WFALGbXhmaYqtTv1VGrUpQpDJ0jN8VmLpQwDRU0j16RbPyg.hGt_z5j8THCiNEhpVvlJmw.WehLBKdyB_eYtDRvHxJHgYwa4GA7f8oKYf3GgIqAAih1eVqU084kHu1lIhC8ibxxziwmFZ4IhBFT-nWgWQrH9thhgqndF4ojtGRBgdHtW3GDAgYV6fgI11h6meyBBuLBs7mkQC5PX8EYsMTDiNE9iNTH4pWtDElc07CGGXlHsm6ntuq7G3sinagZtZMchy1shTY73NTS40FqW37C9HTIPDbrTdsm-USHcGaBMLSmjF5eOZ9Po3p4fhRT42l_gwJc9tlurttYBucvIiO1r_3NB8xGeORizYW1P_P9XGusAFy4L8h8XU9P0FctsMjUFy64LOIK8Qv8YZVq4q82vv-r9uGH6bApUdpCIcYFfGu86w63t1QLQcDT_OYMCqwo9ZmZP5Gd07lB1ypNZbP6hQTgkosp3js3i4K4bFQY7CiSXB_pSTH623TMLHNfUXWMRMIBHmXGr-zTZiKj5vkVUZLjNg.sdBUYvadnwMhkCXP8sABgA
```

I have tried a couple of different python packages, including 2 versions of jose (`python-jose` and `jose`), but could not get jose to work with encryption (did not seem to support the A128KW algorithm).

I am now trying `jwcrypto` but it seems to expect me to generate a new key rather than use my existing one (the one used to encrypt the JWT in ASP.Net):

```
from jwcrypto import jwk, jwe

encrypted_token = request.cookies.get(cookie_name)  
private_key = "MbPeShVmYq3t6w9z"

jwk_key = jwk.JWK()

# not sure how to use my existing "private_key" value, 
# and no support for "A128KW" with jwcrypto despite 
# the documentation saying there is support
key = jwk_key.import_key(alg='A128KW', kty="A256CBC-HS512")

jwe_token = jwe.JWE()
jwe_token.deserialize(encrypted_token)
jwe_token.decrypt(key) # decrypt requires an instance of JWK
decrypted_payload = jwe_token.payload
```

How can I get this to work? Thanks for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `python-jose` DO NOT support JWE. In their [online documentation](https://python-jose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [in the source code](https://github.com/mpdavis/python-jose/) I cannot find any line of code related to the JWE parsing or encryption/decryption.

Hopefully in the library list from jwt.io, I've found [jwcrypto](https://jwcrypto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) that should support such encrypted token (see [this example dealing with A256KW](https://jwcrypto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jwe.html#symmetric-keys)) and in the srouce code we can see [A128KW is listed](https://github.com/latchset/jwcrypto/blob/master/jwcrypto/jwe.py#L33).

You can give it a try.

```
from jwcrypto import jwk, jwe

encrypted_token = request.cookies.get(cookie_name)  

key = jwk.JWK.from_json('{"kty":"oct","k":"TWJQZVNoVm1ZcTN0Nnc5eg"}')

jwe_token = jwe.JWE()
jwe_token.deserialize(encrypted_token)
jwe_token.decrypt(key)
decrypted_payload = jwe_token.payload
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried `jwcrypto` before and struggled with it, but now I'm trying again. The problem is that I already have a private key (created from ASP.Net) and so I need to reuse it but `jwcrypto` seems to suggest that I must use the JWK object and I can only generate a new key to create an instance of that object. There are some `import` methods but cannot figure out how to use my existing key with these methods.

Comment: I have now updated the question to include all my python code

Comment: Not sure if jwcrypto supports A128KW. It clearly says it does in the documentation but the JWK class says:  `JWKTypesRegistry = {'EC': 'Elliptic Curve', 'RSA': 'RSA', 'oct': 'Octet sequence'}` as the "Registry of valid Key Types". Confusing

Comment: The A128KW algorithm requires a symmetric key i.e. `oct` type. With your key `MbPeShVmYq3t6w9z`, the associated JWK is `{"kty":"oct","k":"MbPeShVmYq3t6w9z"}`. You could use the [`from_json` method](https://jwcrypto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jwk.html#jwcrypto.jwk.JWK.from_json) to get a valid objet

Comment: Please note that the parameter `k` should be Base64Url encoded so if it fails you could test with `TWJQZVNoVm1ZcTN0Nnc5eg` instead of `MbPeShVmYq3t6w9z` => `{"kty":"oct","k":"TWJQZVNoVm1ZcTN0Nnc5eg"}`

Comment: Sorry, please ignore my last deleted comment. The JWE part all works and I get back the inner JWT which I now need to figure out how to turn into the original json object (i.e. the claims) so very close now! Only the easy part left! Thanks :)

Comment: All done! I repeated the same step but with the signing key (`ae743683f78d498a9026d0c87020b9d3`) and using the `JWT` object and it worked. Thanks again!